# Implementing Multi Select List as a popup for Views Exposed filter (field of type taxonomy)

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I am trying to implement

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/#popupDemo&ui-state=dialog

in a Views Exposed Filter .
Screenshot of Desired Implementation:
 http://awesomescreenshot.com/00d593vsa8
 http://awesomescreenshot.com/09c593vwae

I have used better exposed filter to show dropdown as checkboxes but I am unable to show the exposed filter as a popup

Is there a way I can do to show filter as a popup as shown in the link above.

The page where I need to implement is :- [Original Site](http://awesomescreenshot.com/052593vo1c)

Can anybody point me on how can I show the exposed filter as popup same as that shown in the demo of jquery mobile